# Android custom image view shape

Tags: android, imageview, android-canvas

I am working on creating a custom ImageView which will crop my image into a hexagon shape and add a border. I was wondering if my approach is correct or if I am doing this the wrong way. There are a bunch of custom libraries out there that already do this but none of them out of the box have the shape I am looking for. That being said, this is more a question about the best practice.

[image: expected result]

You can see the full class in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/tjohn/e2b22114eefe2fc7be09), but the main question is that is this the best approach. It feels wrong to me, partly because of some of the magic numbers which means it could be messed up on some devices.

Here is the meat of the code:

```
      @Override
      protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
        if (drawable == null || getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
          return;
        }

        Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        int dimensionPixelSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.width); // (width and height of ImageView)
        Bitmap drawnBitmap = drawCanvas(bitmap, dimensionPixelSize);
        canvas.drawBitmap(drawnBitmap, 0, 0, null);
      }

      private Bitmap drawCanvas(Bitmap recycledBitmap, int width) {
        final Bitmap bitmap = verifyRecycledBitmap(recycledBitmap, width);

        final Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, width, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, width, width);
        final int offset = (int) (width / (double) 2 * Math.tan(30 * Math.PI / (double) 180)); // (width / 2) * tan(30deg)
        final int length = width - (2 * offset);

        final Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(width / 2, 0); // top
        path.lineTo(0, offset); // left top
        path.lineTo(0, offset + length); // left bottom
        path.lineTo(width / 2, width); // bottom
        path.lineTo(width, offset + length); // right bottom
        path.lineTo(width, offset); // right top
        path.close(); //back to top

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStrokeWidth(4);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint); // draws the bitmap for the image

        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("white"));
        paint.setStrokeWidth(4);
        paint.setDither(true);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        paint.setPathEffect(new CornerPathEffect(10));
        paint.setAntiAlias(true); // draws the border

        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

        return output;
      }
```

I was looking at some iOS code and they are able to apply an actual image as a mask to achieve this result. Is there anyway on Android to do something like that?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview) fits your needs?

Comment: I would say, make your stroke width, offset + X & CornerPathEffect convert to pixels from dp (using TypedValue), but other than that, it looks pretty good. 30 degrees is fine, since 30 degrees is 30 degrees on any device (or anywhere in the universe for that matter)

Comment: @GilMoshayof thanks, I guess I was looking at some iOS code and they are able to apply a svg as a layer over their images. I was hoping there was something I was missing in Android that would allow me to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was looking for the best approach for a long time. Your solution is pretty heavy and doesn't work well with animations. The clipPath approach doesn't use antialiasing and doesn't work with hardware acceleration on certain versions of Android (4.0 and 4.1?). Seems like the best approach (animation friendly, antialiased, pretty clean and hardware accelerated) is to use Canvas layers:

```
Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
private static PorterDuffXfermode pdMode = new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        int saveCount = canvas.saveLayer(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(),
                                         null, Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);

        super.draw(canvas);

        paint.setXfermode(pdMode);
        canvas.drawBitmap(maskBitmap, 0, 0, paint);

        canvas.restoreToCount(saveCount);
        paint.setXfermode(null);
}
```

You can use any kind of mask including custom shapes and bitmaps. [Carbon](https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon) uses such approach to round corners of widgets on the fly.

Comment: Check out my solution here:  https://github.com/tjohn/hexagon_image_view/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/playdraft/hexagonimageview/HexagonImageView.java

Comment: I have two view which are overlapping each other, so How can I apply click event to both of them? Here is my SO link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36793535/custom-shape-button-android

Answer (score 1):

Even though it might work, there a few bad mistakes on this implementation:

- You're allocation some very big objects during `onDraw` phase and that leads to a terrible performance. The most important there is the `createBitmap` but you should avoid at all costs any `new` during `onDraw`. Pre-allocate all necessary objects during initialisation and re-use them during `onDraw`.
- You should setup your `path` just once during `onSizeChanged`. Avoid all that path on every `OnDraw`
- You're relying on usage of `BitmapDrawable` if for example you use `Picasso` to load images from the internet or if you want to use a selector, then this code won't work.
- You should not need to allocate the second bitmap, use `canvas.clipPath` instead to make it efficient.

Said all that a much more efficient pseudo code for the drawing should be:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
   canvas.save(CLIP_SAVE_FLAG); // save the clipping
   canvas.clipPath(path, Region.Op./*have to test which one*/ ); // cut the canvas
   super.onDraw(canvas); // do the normal drawing
   canvas.restore(); // restore the saved clipping
   canvas.drawPath(path, paint); // draw the extra border
}
```

Comment: I agree, that there are performance improvements, this code is not necessarily meant for production but more to demonstrate a general solution. As far as using picasso this does work, it is what I used to load that image. I will look into `clipPath` and see how this works.

Comment: I have confirmed that this works because `PicassoDrawable` extends `BitamapDrawable` see: https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/PicassoDrawable.java#L36

Comment: Thanks for the tips about the performance, but @zielony makes a good point about the animations and hardware acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

add dependency in build.gradle

```
   implementation 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
   implementation group: 'net.sf.kxml', name: 'kxml2-min', version: '2.3.0'
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.HexagonImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="350dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
HexagonImageView imageView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imageView=findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);
}}
```

output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

add dependency in build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
    <com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.mask.PorterShapeImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        app:siShape="@drawable/shape" />
    
</LinearLayout>
```

activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView=findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);
    }
}
```

drawable resource

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FFC107" />
    <padding android:left="7dp"
        android:top="7dp"
        android:right="7dp"
        android:bottom="7dp" />
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="0dip"
        android:topRightRadius="70dip"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="70dip"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dip" />
</shape>
```

output

[image: output]