# Custom Shape Button Android

Tags: android, android-custom-view, shapes

I have to address this type of views which has buttons below example.
http://www.planet1107.net/blog/custom-shape-uibutton-tutorial/

It is in the iOS. so is there any way to make it in Android.
I also have to give click events on all of those buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend just exporting these custom images to pngs. Then adding the pngs to your Android project and simply referencing them in the code or XML. Then on a click event you can simply change the icon to indicate that it has been clicked and if the user clicks on it one more time change it back.

This will also ensure that the Android images look identical to the iOS ones.

Comment: can you please give me some example code? It's quiet tough to understand.

Comment: To simply, I will be more simple for use to take there custom made icons and create an image of them. That way you can simply add the icons in your drawable folder and reference them in your XML or in your code.  I am not sure if the custom icons changes when you click on them, but if they do you can simply add a image of the unclicked state and a image of the clicked state. That way when a user presses on it you can simply change the background to the clicked state. Add a boolean to the class to keep track if the button has been clicked or not.